# How AND between two operators works?

Tags: java, php, eclipse, netbeans, logic

I have this code, it results '2'. I googled and searched books but found no good answer that helped me.

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
int x = i & j;
System.out.println (x);
```

Can anyone can explain.

Comment: In this case it's a bitwise operation. Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for details

Comment: It basically goes bit-by-bit for each integer and ANDs the two bits. So it would AND the first bit of each integer, then the second bit, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, '&' is the [bitwise and operator](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/bitops.html).  Bits are set in the result only if they are set in both of the operands:

Here's the operation:

```
  2: 00000010
& 3: 00000011
-----------
  2: 00000010
```

Of course here, ints are 32 bits, and I only showed the last 8, but the first 24 are all zeroes for these numbers anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bitwise operator.

2 in binary is '10'.  3 in binary is '11'.  The bitwise & operator compares them like so:

```
 10
&11
 --
 10
```

For each column where both numbers are 1, it will return 1.  In this case, the result is '10', which as an int is equal to 2.

Answer (score 1):

&  is the bitwise AND
&& is the logical AND.

2 & 3 delivers correctly 2.

Expressed in binary representation:

```
10
 11
 --
 10
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a bitwise operator that works as follows:

```
0 & 0 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

and hence `2 & 3 = 2`:

```
2 ==> 00000000000000000000000000000010
      &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
3 ==> 00000000000000000000000000000011
---------
2 ==> 00000000000000000000000000000010
```

Comment: Brilliant @eng Fouad. I got this. This is bitwise operator I knew, but, now I understand how it actually works. Thnk you.

Answer (score 1):

Take these examples:

```
System.out.println(2 & 3);
System.out.println(3 & 4);
System.out.println(8 & 4);
System.out.println(9 & 5);
System.out.println(11 & 7);
// binary representation of above operations
System.out.println(0b10 & 0b11);
System.out.println(0b11 & 0b100);
System.out.println(0b1000 & 0b100);
System.out.println(0b1001 & 0b101);
System.out.println(0b1011 & 0b111);
```

They result in the output of:

```
2
0
0
1
3
2
0
0
1
3
```

Then go back and look at the binary representations and notice how the resulting answers are the Bitwise AND of the numbers (and not the Logical AND &&)